# How to handle destructors in DLL exported interfaces

Tags: c++, dll, destructor, dllexport, pure-virtual

I'm trying to export a class from a DLL. I read this article on doing so: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28969/HowTo-Export-C-classes-from-a-DLL

The "mature" approach suggest, that an abstract class is used, so I have:

```
// Header
class IFoo{
public:
    virtual int getBar() = 0;
}

class Foo: public IFoo {...}

DLLEXPORT IFoo* Create();
DLLEXPRT void Free(IFoo* inst);

//DLL cpp
IFoo* Create(){ return new Foo; }
void Free(IFoo* inst){ delete inst; }
```

What puzzles me: If I don't have a virtual destructor, then `delete inst` won't call Foos destructor and may leak memory. How am I supposed to handle that? The article does not give an answer to that.

Using `virtual ~IFoo(){}` is not possible, as that adds an implementation to IFoo which causes problems (explained in a answer to a question in the article for an inline virtual function) and `virtual ~IFoo() = 0;` fails with a linker error on the undefined symbol `~IFoo`

What is the safe way to go? How should the Free/Release functions be implemented?

Comment: Don't make things more complicated than they need to be. Just provide a virtual destructor in `IFoo` and export its definition.

Comment: You can add a virtual Free() function to the interface instead.  Casting *inst* to Foo* is another way, not better.

Comment: @HansPassant: Why not simply a virtual destructor?

Comment: I'm just handing him bullets, loading the gun is up to him.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, let's note that the issue is specific to Visual Studio's handling of DLLs. GCC and Clang both have a stable ABI (Itanium ABI) which guarantees the compatibility of libraries compiled with different versions.

Now, as mentioned, the issue you face here is ABI instability, however parts of the ABI are stable (the virtual table layout) otherwise the strategy presented would simply not work.

Therefore, simply having a `virtual` destructor should work. There will be no name mangling issue because of the call via the virtual table.

Also, note that in modern C++ returning a raw pointer is a no-no, but name mangling prevents the use of a smart pointer...

```
// Foo.h
class Foo {
public:
    virtual int get() = 0;
    virtual ~Foo();

protected:
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(Foo&&) = default;
    Foo(Foo const&) = default;
    Foo& operator=(Foo) = default;
};

// WARNING: immediately capture this Foo* in a smart pointer,
//          or suffer from memory leak (and worse).
Foo* createFoo(); // factory behind

// Foo.cpp
Foo::~Foo() {} // not inline
```

Comment: So the solution is simply a virtual destructor implemented in the DLLs cpp?
And I'm stuck with C++03 ATM can I achieve the same protected constructors with that? Inline implementation is forbidden I guess...

Comment: @Flamefire: I would think that a non-inline destructor should work; the issue I see with an inline destructor is that it will generate multiple times code for the destructor: once per DLL, and since they use incompatible versions... as for C++03, just do not use the `Foo(Foo&&)` constructor, and of course write the body fully (as you won't have `= default`).