# vs c++ dll - scalar deleteing destructor

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I'm programing in visual studio c++. I have Field, IField, Map and IMap in DLL. I create interfaces IField and IMap to have access to Field and Map in unit test. When i run this simple code in unit test:

```
IMap m;
IField f(3, 4);
m.shoot(f);
```

I have following error:

> LNK2019   unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall
>   Field::~Field(void)" (??1Field@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function
>   "public: virtual void * __thiscall Field::`**scalar deleting
>   destructor**'(unsigned int)" (??_GField@@UAEPAXI@Z)   TestShipGameDll

```
#pragma once
class Field
{
public:
    Field(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
    virtual ~Field() {}
protected:
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

.

```
#ifdef IFIELD_EXPORTS  
#define IFIELD_API __declspec(dllexport)   
#else  
#define IFIELD_API __declspec(dllimport)   
#endif  

class IField : 
    public Field 
{
public:
    IFIELD_API IField(int x, int y) :Field(x, y)
    IFIELD_API virtual ~IField() {}
};
```

.

```
class Map
{
public:
    Map();
    virtual ~Map();
    void shoot(Field field) 
    {
        //here is empty body of function
    }    

};
```

.

```
#ifdef IMAP_EXPORTS  
#define IMAP_API __declspec(dllexport)   
#else  
#define IMAP_API __declspec(dllimport)   
#endif  

class IMap :
    public Map
{
public:
    IMAP_API IMap() {}
    IMAP_API virtual ~IMap() {}
    IMAP_API void shoot(Field field)
    {
        Map::shoot(field);
    }
};
```

.
It's weird. It looks like it was missing copying constructor but I do not have any pointers in Field. Only automatic variables x and y. Do you have any tips to resolve this fancy error?

Comment: `m.shoot(f)` is going to construct a temporary `Field` object, that needs to be destroyed when the call returns. To destroy an object, you need the destructor. The linker is complaining, that it cannot find one for `Field`. That's not surprising, as it isn't exported.

Comment: Why linker is not complaining about constructor of the `Field`?
Because of init list `IFIELD_API IField(int x, int y) :Field(x, y)`?
Anyway, when the method has to be exposed? Thanks :-)

Comment: Most ambiguous answers ever... I had similar error and I could solve it by simply declaring the destructor as "virtual", see there for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32444685/4916074

Answer (score 0):

You have to export the whole class with `IFIELD_API` - otherwise the compiler-generated functions are not visible outside the shared library and you will get linker errors.